# Creating Stateful nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

When I say **Stateful Node**, I mean a node that carries ‘state info,’ such as the path that leads to this node. E.g. R1 is a node, and

- state1: link coming from path 1
- state2: link coming from path 2

Is there any way I could create such a node in Neo4j? While traversing such a node, I expect it to behave like this:

- if state 1, and input is x, then [:has] node1
- if state one and input is y, then stop
- if state two and input is z, then [: has] node 2.

I want to convert node R1 to a stateful node so that it keeps the information mentioned above. Does Neo4J support such nodes? If so, could you guide me to a resource? Also, does the cipher query support the ‘stateful’ approach so I can set the state according to the path from which R1 is produced?

[image: nodes]

Answer (score 0):

In the Neo4j architecture, a relationship is a doubly linked-list that stores pointers to the start and end nodes.

It sounds like what you're looking to do is create nodes that store that same information for all relationships that touch it, and then have behavior based on how the graph reaches them.

This is more akin to logic control, and Cypher handles that through filters on relationship type, node labels, and properties.

However, you can always set properties of nodes based on queries. For example:

```
MATCH (:AUTH_T)-[:HAS]->(n:R1)
SET R1.reached_by = "HAS"
```

Then you could do something with that in the future, like if you want to know if node n was reached by another method.